# Registering multiple file types for my iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone

I've built an app that exports data via email. It takes the data, encodes in an NSData object adds an extension, then attaches it to an email. All of that works perfectly. The issue I'm having is when I open one of those emails, one of the file types I registered works fine. My app appears in the list of target apps and I can import the data with no issues.

For the other file type my app doesn't show up in the list of target apps. For both types, I've created entries in info.plist for Document Type, and for each type I've created a custom UTI with file extension.

I've looked at the configuration for both and the only differences I can see are the UTI I'm using, the extension for the UTI and the name of the document.

Am I missing something?

Relevant portions of info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>appname144</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>appname Army Archive</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.appnameeapp.archive.army</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>appname144</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>appname List Archive</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.appnameapp.archive.list</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>appname Army</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.appnameapp.archive.army</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>puclic.filename-extension</key>
            <string>wfarmy</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>appname List</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.appnameapp.archive.list</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>wflist</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Post the relevant sections of your Info.plist

Comment: I've added the sections of my info.plist

Comment: Typo - you have `puclic.filename-extension` for your `wfarmy` extension.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks I don't know how I missed that.